# How to get last record in mongodb using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I use Ruby on rails, mongoid for my application. I want to get last record in a collection. I try

```
Person.find().sort({'_id',-1})
```

but, this command does not work on ruby. How can I achieve to get the last record?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Person.asc(:created_at).last
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you give me any resoruce address that you know on ruby and mongoid? Thanks again.